# Laptop SSD to desktop

Tags: windows, laptop, ssd, desktop-computer

I was wondering if I could use the SSD from my old laptop and put it into my new custom build desktop pc.

If so do I have to order the windows 10 product again or can i use the one on my laptop (if stored on the SSD) with my new PC?

Thanks in advance.

SSD:    Intel 600p 512 GB M.2-2280 NVME Solid State Drive

Motherboard:    Asus PRIME B660M-A D4 Micro ATX LGA1700 Motherboard

Answer (score 0):

You can use any drive anywhere (exceptions are very rare -> e.g. SSDs from XBox) provided the motherboard supports the drive's form factor and type or trough an adapter. Your [motherboard](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards-Components/Motherboards/PRIME/PRIME-B660M-A-D4/techspec/) supports it directly.

Regarding the Windows license it depends. If it came with the laptop then it's an OEM license and can't be used in a different computer.

Answer (score 0):

From a hardware POV this should be fine - you just neef to make sure your desktop has an appropriate interface available for it.  This is slightly less likely to be a problem for acSATA ssd.

From a software POV, If you have an OEM version (which is typical for laptops) Windows is normally licensed per motherboard, so you cant legally use that license in your new build.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, your license may not legally allow you to use the Windows on a different motherboard. Check that first.
However, if you need to and decide to buy a new license, you don't need to re-install, you can just change your Windows license key in the settings to the new one.